# How to add Boost c++ into a makefile

Tags: c++, boost, makefile

I am using `boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp` within class of a cpp file `boost.cpp`

My main in in `practice.cpp`

How do i add the Boost into the make file

The current make file looks like this:

```
practice.exe        :   practice.o 
    g++ -Wall -O2 practice.cpp -lws2_32 -o practice.exe 
            
practice.o      :   practice.cpp 
    g++ -c -O2 -Wall practice.cpp
    
clean:
    del *.o
    del *.exe
```

Comment: You need to download the multiprecision source code: https://github.com/boostorg/multiprecision/releases/tag/v1.79

Comment: Thenyou need a `-I/path/to/multiprecision/include` during the compile step.

Comment: @user14717 that's not how that works. Multiprecision depends on other parts of Boost

Comment: @sehe: It is, because that's what we just made work.

Comment: @user14717 It implies that you had other boost headers lying around: https://pdimov.github.io/boostdep-report/boost-1.79.0/multiprecision.html

Comment: @user14717 Oh wait. I should have looked at your exact link. I didn't know Boost Multiprecision had a "standalone" offering. I visually recognized the github repo URL so I didn't see that.

Comment: @sehe: No worries; we just made it work a few weeks ago.

Comment: @user14717 i have downloaded the boost library from its site, how can i use that instead of using the standalone multiprecision library. how should i add the path, when its in a different folder to the project?

Answer (score 1):

So, the general idea is to just system install boost and let the compiler find it in the default include paths.

E.g. on a debian

```
 apt install libboost-all-dev
```

Should be enough. Boost Multiprecision *itself* is header-only. So if you only need `cpp_int`, `cpp_dec_float` and `cpp_bin_float`, you're done. You might want GMP/MPFR support, in which case you need to link those libraries with the additional linker flags `-lgmp` or `-lmpfr`.

If you need Serialization support, also link `-lboost_serialization` which would be installed in the default library paths with the system-wide Boost package we installed at the start.